# Metadata version mismatch for module @angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

Tags: angular, angular-material2

`ng build` fails and produce following error

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module E:/angularWorkspace/klinik-web/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol
 AppMaterialModule in E:/angularWorkspace/klinik-web/src/app/app-material.module.ts, resolving symbol AppMaterialModule in E:/angularWorkspace/klinik-web/src/app/app-material.module.ts
    at syntaxError (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:240:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (E:\angularWorkspace\klinik-web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:493:24)
    at <anonymous>
```

Here is my `package.json` file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.7",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
```

It seems error produced by angular material. If i exclude this package it runs well. What am I missing?

Comment: Material 5 needs Angular 5 to work. You are using Angular 4. Upgrade to Angular 5.

Comment: I have run `npm update`. Only `@angular/cdk` and `rxjs` got updated. I thought all packages are updated. Should I update all package manually?

Comment: Yes, update the packages manually. `npm update` will not update major versions when using `^` in front of the version numbers in the *package.json*. FYI, the latest version of Angular is 5.2.9. Be prepared for the possibility that you will have to change some code as a result of this upgrade. Major version changes can include breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks @R.Richards. I didn't know about that fact of `npm update`. updating packages manually. I'll let you know if problem solved.

Comment: This might be helpful  https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Comment: @R.Richards It is working now. I had to update both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this error. My application is angular 4.2.4 and angular material 5.2.4..I know angular update version will solve this issue.But i dont want update my angular version 4.2.4. So is there any way to use angular material for this angular version 4.2.4.. ?

package.json

"@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",

"@angular/cdk":"^5.2.4",
"@angular/material" : "^5.2.4"